What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a one-way between subjects MANOVA versus a split-plot repeated measures ANOVA?
For example, I would like to analyse the difference in heart rate, breathing rate, height, weight, and  number of hair between three species (cats, dogs, and rats). This is a nonsensical example of course, what are the advantages of conducting a one-way between-subject MANOVA vs a split-plot ANOVA?
For the MANOVA, the between-subject factor would be species and the DVs are as mentioned.
For the split-plot ANOVA, the between-subject factor would be species and each level of the within-subject factor would be the different DVs.
I do understand that the variables are not repeated measures and I intended for the example to be of such a nature.

I personally hate MANOVA and as this article and as this episode of Quantitude spell out, MANOVA really needs to die. Though they do a great job of burying it as a technique, my personal beefs with MANOVA are 1) It doesn't actually test what people think it does  2) It deals with Type I errors in horrific ways and 3) It holds on to way too many unrealistic assumptions and poor interpretation when much better techniques already exist for multivariate analysis (e.g. DDA or SEM).
As for the split-plot design, I'm not sure what a split-plot ANOVA would contribute here and your example doesn't really make sense given these aren't truly repeated measures. Though you can clarify what you mean if my understanding is poor.
